# Mount folders to specific partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, 18.04, lvm

I'm relatively new to Linux/Ubuntu and just installed 18.04 LTS Server on a VPS.

During setup I created 3 partitions using LVM (other than boot):

```
/
swap
/var
```

This is the output from df -h:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    395M  2.2M  393M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/nc--vg-root   19G  2.1G   16G  12% /
tmpfs                    2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                    2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/nc--vg-data   53G  645M   49G   2% /var
/dev/vda1                704M  144M  510M  22% /boot
tmpfs                    395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Some more output, from from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/vda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf805ed87

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *       2048   1499135   1497088  731M 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       1501182 167770111 166268930 79.3G  5 Extended
/dev/vda5       1501184 167770111 166268928 79.3G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/vda5_crypt: 79.3 GiB, 85127593984 bytes, 166264832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/nc--vg-root: 18.6 GiB, 19998441472 bytes, 39059456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/nc--vg-swap: 7.5 GiB, 7998537728 bytes, 15622144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/nc--vg-data: 53.2 GiB, 57126420480 bytes, 111575040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This server will function as a web, mail and cloud server.  How can I ensure all the data related folders are mounted under /var  (or /dev/mapper/nc--vg-data).  /var is already taken care of, but I also want to mount /home and perhaps some other folders on the same partition as that's where I'll probably be storing emails. This partition has the most storage allocated to it so I want to keep all the data heavy stuff there.

Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "Folders" are pretty pictures displayed in a GUI; the structures in a filesystem are called "directories". (The difference is that directories exist independent of any program, whereas folders may or may not be ephemeral names created by some graphical shell.)
- You've got is exactly backwards: you don't mount directories on partitions, you mount filesystems on directories.
- To place `/home` under `/var`, assuming we are speaking of a freshly installed server with no GUI:

  1. Create a directory `/var/home`, then
  2. Move everything from `/home` to `/var/home` with

     ```
     cd /home && for d in *; do sudo mv "$d" "/var/home/$d"; done
     ```
  3. Mount bind temporarily `/var/home` on `/home`:

     ```
     sudo mount --bind /var/home /home
     ```
  4. Add

     ```
     /var/home /home none bind 0 0
     ```

     at the end of `/etc/fstab`; this will `mount --bind` the directory `/var/home` on `/home` at boot.
  5. Reboot and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason your <<cd /home && for d in * do sudo mv "$d" "/var/home/$d"; done>> kept giving me an error (something about done being an invalid argument).  Anyway, I manually copied the user directories (there is only one at this point) and did the rest per your suggestion, which worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @starfly: There was a semicolon missing :(